# Hosting TFS on Azure or AWS

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, tfs, azure-devops

We will be hosting TFS in a private cloud on VM(s). Are there technical differences to hosting TFS on Azure or AWS, or is it only a matter of pricing and which cloud a team prefers and has past knowledge of? I also think we won't go the Visual Studio Online route.

Answer (score 4):

At InCycle, we have a full TFS 2015 installation hosted in Azure spread across something like 6-8 VMs. You'll need to take into account the standard considerations (virtual machine sizing and performance), especially on the data tier, which should have plenty of fast disks and lots of CPU and RAM.

You'll also need to consider Active Directory sync and how you'll get access to things like build drops on-premise from Azure.

Honestly, VSO will almost certainly be a lot cheaper for you, and you won't have to worry about the infrastructure requirements or upgrading TFS on a regular basis.

The ALM rangers have excellent guidance on this, as well: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2014/06/06/team-foundation-server-on-azure-iaas-guidance.aspx

Comment: Are there any data security considerations between VSO and VM hosted TFS? I come from an enterprise perspective.

Comment: I'd say VSO is a bit more secure by default. Everything in VSO is over HTTPS automatically. Meanwhile, it's a bit of extra work to set up SSL for on-prem TFS.